# ¿Se puede crear un Id autoincrementable por dia en MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Tengo la tabla `reportes` con el campo `id(int, AI, PK)` y el campo `fecha(date, PK)`, quiero que el 1er registro del campo `Id` de cada dia sea 1 y apartir de ahi continue el incrementable, ejemplo:

```
Id  fecha
1   2019-05-19
2   2019-05-19
3   2019-05-19
1   2019-05-20
2   2019-05-20
```

¿Es posible que con la configuración de que la `primary key` sea el ID + FECHA haga en automatico en cada `INSERT` lo que pretendo?

¿O la única forma es que lo haga con ciertas condiciones desde un `store procedure`?

Al momento esta configuración no me funciona, me inserta el numero maximo que continua en el campo `id`, si especifico el `id` manualmente si funciona.

Comment: No lo puedes hacer con PK ni con DEFAULT. Tu opción mas simple sería con un Trigger.

Comment: Lo pudiste hacer? yo te recomiendo que mantengas el ID autonumerico incremental asi como esta, y crees otro campo que sea el ID que quieres tener, que por cierto vas a tener que hacerlo con algun disparador al momento del insert

Comment: Efectivamente lo hice muy similar a tu consejo, gracias de igual manera

Answer (score 0):

La solución que encontre fue crear una columna extra `id_dia` y cambiar el tipo de dato de fecha a `datetime`,y mi tabla quedo de la siguiente manera: `id(int, AI, PK), id_dia(int), fecha(datetime)` y meti lo siguiente a un `store procedure`:

```
SET @ID:=(Select case when ID_dia is null then ifnull(min(ID_dia),0)+1 else max(ID_dia)+1 end as ID_dia FROM tabla where date(fecha) = curdate());   

INSERT INTO `tabla`(`ID_dia`, `fecha`) VALUES (@id,now());
```

Si alguien tiene una mejor solución adelante, Saludos!